# Preload a spritesheet using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a spritesheet now what i want to do is to preload the spritesheet images how can i get through it using javascript.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not HTML5 nor specifically jQuery related. A sprite sheet is just an image, so preload like you would any other image. That said, a "jQuery way" would be:

```
var $mySprite = $("<img>").attr("src", "myURL");
```

Voila.

Comment: but how can we show preloading image above the image @Torster Walter

Comment: What do you mean `show preloading` image? Do you want to show that the image is still loading?

Comment: `$mySprite.bind("load", loadFinished);` In the `loadFinished` function you can hide whatever layer or loading indicator you displayed before starting to load the image. Since you don't provide _any_ details in your question about your environment it's hard to give you _any_ concrete advice on this.