# How to use preloaded CSS spritesheet in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, image-preloader

I'm making a game using HTML5 canvas. I have a large spritesheet which contains every sprite I'll need within the game. I have read a bit on what might be the best preloading asset technique, and I haven't found anything concrete.

So, I decided I'll just choose one technique: CSS spritesheets. I've used http://www.spritecow.com/ where I've loaded the spritesheet.gif file and generated the CSS code. The thing is that I couldn't find any tutorials on how to actually USE the individual sprites within javascript and the canvas element!

Can someone give me a hand? If you know any other preloading technique or library that is better (can preload images and sounds, if possible).

EDIT: A solution with jQuery is fine too.

Comment: Are you asking about how to preload the spritesheet or how to apply it to elements?

Comment: Hmm. Both, I think. I want to use it within the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Preloading:***

> A sprite sheet is just an image, so preload like you would any other image. That said, a "jQuery way" would be: `var $mySprite = $("<img>").attr("src", "myURL");`

(Source: [Preload a spritesheet using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842611/preload-a-spritesheet-using-jquery))

***Applying to elements:***

No need to use javascript as this can be done with simple css.

1 - Add a `sprite` class to every element that uses the spritesheet:

**html:** `<div class="sprite">`

**css:** `.sprite { background-image:url("your spritesheet url here") }`

2 - Add ids to your elements, and then matching css `background-position` rules, according to the location of the specific element's image on the spritesheet. e.g.

**html:** `<div class="sprite" id="fire"></div>`

**css:**

```
#fire {
  background-position: -100px -50px;
  height: 20px;
  width:  40px;
}
```